# How can i update the password encrypted From VB.NET using MsSql Server12

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2012

```
Public Function Encrypt(clearText As String) As String
    Dim EncryptionKey As String = "MAKV2SPBNI99212"
    Dim clearBytes As Byte() = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText)
    Using encryptor As Aes = Aes.Create()
        Dim pdb As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, New Byte() {&H49, &H76, &H61, &H6E, &H20, &H4D, _
         &H65, &H64, &H76, &H65, &H64, &H65, &H76})
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32)
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16)
        Using ms As New MemoryStream()
            Using cs As New CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length)
                cs.Close()
            End Using
            clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())
        End Using
    End Using
    Return clearText
End Function

Public Function Decrypt(cipherText As String) As String
    Dim EncryptionKey As String = "MAKV2SPBNI99212"
    cipherText = cipherText.Replace(" ", "+")
    Dim cipherBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText)
    Using encryptor As Aes = Aes.Create()
        Dim pdb As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, New Byte() {&H49, &H76, &H61, &H6E, &H20, &H4D, _
         &H65, &H64, &H76, &H65, &H64, &H65, &H76})
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32)
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16)
        Using ms As New MemoryStream()
            Using cs As New CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length)
                cs.Close()
            End Using
            cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray())
        End Using
    End Using
    Return cipherText
End Function
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you should just need to decrypt the existing value with the old EncryptionKey "MAKV2SPBNI99212", then re-encrypt with a new EncryptionKey.

```
decryptedText = Decrypt(encryptedText, "MAKV2SPBNI99212")
encryptedText = Encrypt(decryptedText, "MY_NEW_KEY")
```

Updating your Encrypt and Decrypt functions to allow passing of EncryptionKey as parameter, like:

```
Public Function Encrypt(ByVal clearText As String, ByVal encryptionKey As String) As String
    Dim clearBytes As Byte() = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText)
    Using encryptor As Aes = Aes.Create()
        Dim pdb As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(encryptionKey, New Byte() {&H49, &H76, &H61, &H6E, &H20, &H4D, _
         &H65, &H64, &H76, &H65, &H64, &H65, &H76})
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32)
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16)
        Using ms As New MemoryStream()
            Using cs As New CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length)
                cs.Close()
            End Using
            clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())
        End Using
    End Using
    Return clearText
End Function

Public Function Decrypt(ByVal cipherText As String, ByVal encryptionKey As String) As String
    cipherText = cipherText.Replace(" ", "+")
    Dim cipherBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText)
    Using encryptor As Aes = Aes.Create()
        Dim pdb As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(encryptionKey, New Byte() {&H49, &H76, &H61, &H6E, &H20, &H4D, _
         &H65, &H64, &H76, &H65, &H64, &H65, &H76})
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32)
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16)
        Using ms As New MemoryStream()
            Using cs As New CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length)
                cs.Close()
            End Using
            cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray())
        End Using
    End Using
    Return cipherText
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks guys..  it help a lot :)